# Azure Functions 2 - How to control json serialization settings

Tags: azure, json.net, azure-functions

I want to be able to control how json is formatted when I return a content result from a Azure Function (V2). The following is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```
[FunctionName("CreateThing")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> CreateThingAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "thing")]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    try{
        var result = await GetResultAsync(req);
        return new CreatedResult($"thing/{result.id}", result);
    }
    catch(ErrorException) {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(e.Error);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to control how the results are formatted when they are returned, without using attributes on my models? I want to be able to use JsonSerializerSettings but I cant find a way of being able to configure this for the results that are returned as per the example above.

Comment: Have you tried [JsonResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_JsonResult__ctor_System_Object_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_) with JsonSerializerSettings?

Comment: JsonResult with JsonSerialiserSettings could work, but it does not allow setting of the status code or additional response headers out of the box. Ideally I could set up the responsibility of Json formatting elsewhere. If this was an MVC app it would be simple. Function Apps seem to give me ALOT less control with many fewer extension hooks.

Comment: There is a (closed) issue on the AzureFunctions repo in Github where someone described how to do that by creating a response from the HttpRequest object. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/298

Comment: Thanks @SebastianAchatz. I may well have to do something like that. Its a shame there is no way to hook into the function response after it leaves the static function method. I will probably end up creating something that can map all ObjectResult to JsonResult, just to use the override that allows me to set JsonSerializerSettings .

Comment: After more looking around I think this kind of scenario may be addressed in an iminent release of the Azure Function SDK/API. Dependency Injection is coming soon - hopefully the Azure functions team will take the opportunity to expose the WebJobs pipeline extensions which would make this achievable.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same problem myself today.

As Jerry commented, `JsonResult` can get you most of the way there; it supports a `StatusCode` property:

```
return new JsonResult(new WorkQueuedResponseMessage
{
    ...
}, Constants.CommunicationJsonSerializerSettings)
{
    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status202Accepted,
};
```

For custom headers, my solution is a bit more hacky. I define my own `IActionResult` that just sticks headers onto another `IActionResult`:

```
private sealed class HeaderActionResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly IActionResult _result;

    public HeaderActionResult(IActionResult result)
    {
        _result = result;
        HeaderDictionary = new HeaderDictionary();
        Headers = new ResponseHeaders(HeaderDictionary);
    }

    public IHeaderDictionary HeaderDictionary { get; }

    public ResponseHeaders Headers { get; }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        foreach (var header in HeaderDictionary)
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append(header.Key, header.Value);
        await _result.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

I can then define helper methods if desired:

```
public static IActionResult EnableCacheHeaders(this IActionResult response, TimeSpan time)
{
    return new HeaderActionResult(response)
    {
        Headers =
        {
            CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
            {
                Public = true,
                MaxAge = time,
            },
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow + time,
        },
    };
}
```

and use them as such:

```
return new JsonResult(new WorkAlreadyCompletedResponseMessage
{
    ...
}, Constants.CommunicationJsonSerializerSettings).EnableCacheHeaders(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
```

This works as a way to return `IActionResult` with custom JSON serialization, status codes, and headers, while using as many ASP.NET Core types as possible. Hopefully in the future we will get a better integration / injection story.